# Accessing items based off list of indices in iterables

Tags: python

I have about 40 million lines of text to parse through and I want to treat each line as a split string and then ask for multiple slices (or subscripts, whatever they are called) using a list of numbers I generate in a method.

```
# ...
other_file = open('output.txt','w')
list = [1, 4, 5, 7, ...]
for line in open(input_file):
    other_file.write(line.split(',')[i for i in list])
```

the subscript can't take this generator I have shown, but I want to ask the split line for multiple entries in it without having to iterate through the list in every line.

I apologize, I know this is a simple answer but I just can't think of it. It's so late!

Comment: Did you want each item (ie, element in `line`) on seperate lines?

Answer (score 4):

CSV module can help you

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(input_file, 'r'))
writer = csv.writer(open(output_file, 'w'))
fields = (1,4,5,7,...)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([row[i] for i in fields])
```

For further improvements, open files with [context managers](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `list` as a variable name - remember there is a builtin called `list`

```
other_file = open('output.txt','w')
lst = [1,4,5,7,...]
for line in open(input_file):
    fields = line.split(',')
    other_file.write(",".join(fields[i] for i in lst) + "\n")
```

For further improvement use context managers to open/close the files for you

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from csv import reader, writer

fields = 1,4,5,7

row_filter = itemgetter(*fields)

with open('inp.txt', 'r') as inp:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
        writer(out).writerows(map(row_filter, reader(inp)))
```